# Consolidate Planner Subtasks into one cell in Excel with Power-Automate

Tags: excel, power-automate, microsoft-planner

I am trying to use power-automate to add rows with MS planner tasks once the task is completed. Part of the details I need are the checklist items (subtasks). Currently, when I just add "Checklist Title", it creates a row for each subtask that exists in the checklist. How can I get it all to show up in one cell in excel, separated by commas, so that I only have one row per task?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Just use Office Scripts to add a function like =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A100)

Comment: I suppose you're already iterating over the tasks, and inside the loop you have "Add row to spreadsheet" or something like that. Is that correct? If that's the case, you can create a string variable and for each task you can append the text to it. You should take the "add row..." out of the loop, and using it only once, using the variable.